# How Do I Resolve the Error 'not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)' When Plotting in Python?

Tags: python, plot

I want to create a plot of density superposed on the map grid of longitude and latitude using colors to indicate the density along the pretend satellite track. The attached photo is the plot of latitude and longitude showing the pretend satellite track. [image]

I have arrays satlong for longitude, satlat for latitude, and dens for the density values. I will show the first few values of each to give you an idea. There are 1111 rows of data for all the arrays I am using - satlong, satlat, and dens.

Dens:

```
6.042968853864891e-12
6.042894605467602e-12
6.042777396826408e-12
6.042616263531836e-12
6.042410211830538e-12
```

Satlat:

```
0       50.224832
1       50.536422
2       50.847827
3       51.159044
4       51.470068
```

Satlong:

```
0       108.873007
1       108.989510
2       109.107829
3       109.228010
4       109.350097
```

This is the code I am using to plot but am getting the error: 'not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)' and I'm not sure how to fix it. The error is appearing at the pcolormesh line of code.

```
import matplotlib.cm as cm

cmap = cm.get_cmap('BrBG')

cs = plt.pcolormesh(satlong, satlat, dens, cmap = cmap)

plt.title('Ephemeris Satellite Trajectory')
plt.xlabel('Longitude')
plt.ylabel('Latitude')

plt.savefig('Ephemeris Satellite Trajectory', dpi=200, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.025)

cb = plt.colorbar(cs, orientation = 'vertical')
cb.set_label(r'Density')
```

This is the entire error I am getting:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-f2cc502477b2> in <module>
      3 cmap = cm.get_cmap('BrBG')
      4 
----> 5 cs = plt.pcolormesh(satlong, satlat, dens, cmap = cmap)
      6 
      7 plt.title('Ephemeris Satellite Trajectory')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in pcolormesh(alpha, norm, cmap, vmin, vmax, shading, antialiased, data, *args, **kwargs)
   2771         *args, alpha=alpha, norm=norm, cmap=cmap, vmin=vmin,
   2772         vmax=vmax, shading=shading, antialiased=antialiased,
-> 2773         **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)
   2774     sci(__ret)
   2775     return __ret

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1808                         "the Matplotlib list!)" % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1809                         RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1810             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1811 
   1812         inner.__doc__ = _add_data_doc(inner.__doc__,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in pcolormesh(self, alpha, norm, cmap, vmin, vmax, shading, antialiased, *args, **kwargs)
   5980         allmatch = (shading == 'gouraud')
   5981 
-> 5982         X, Y, C = self._pcolorargs('pcolormesh', *args, allmatch=allmatch)
   5983         Ny, Nx = X.shape
   5984         X = X.ravel()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in _pcolorargs(funcname, allmatch, *args)
   5547                 if isinstance(Y, np.ma.core.MaskedArray):
   5548                     Y = Y.data
-> 5549             numRows, numCols = C.shape
   5550         else:
   5551             raise TypeError(

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Comment: When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`). The Traceback will show you which line caused it. Do you understand what the error means?  Do all your *variables* conform to the arguments types that the functions expect?

Comment: @wwii I just edited my post. Thank you

Comment: @wwii When I try that I get another error. This is the line I tried to fix according to the documentation: `cs = plt.pcolormesh([satlong, satlat,] dens, cmap=cmap)` and this is the new error I'm getting: `File "<ipython-input-44-6cca3381dc32>", line 6
    cs = plt.pcolormesh([satlong, satlat,] dens, cmap=cmap)
                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: `satlong` and `satlat` look like Pandas object. try - `satlong.values()` and `satlat.values()` or `.to_numpy()`

Comment: @wwii Yes ther are Pandas objects. I tried to do `satlong.values()` and `satlat.values()` and got this error: `---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-7795d4586b0e> in <module>
      4 
      5 #cs = plt.pcolormesh([satlong, satlat,] dens, cmap = cmap)
----> 6 cs = plt.pcolormesh(satlong.values(), satlat.values(), dens, cmap=cmap)
      7 
      8 plt.title('Ephemeris Satellite Trajectory')

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable`

Comment: @wwii and when I try to add `.to_numpy() I get this error: 
`ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-cf1e8b8548fb> in <module>
      4 
      5 #cs = plt.pcolormesh([satlong, satlat,] dens, cmap = cmap)
----> 6 cs = plt.pcolormesh(satlong.to_numpy(), satlat.to_numpy(), dens, cmap=cmap)
      7 
      8 plt.title('Ephemeris Satellite Trajectory')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`